# Cannont invoke '' with an argument list of type ''

Tags: swift, swift2

In Playground(Xcode 7.2(7C68)) I am using a generics function and getting the the error:

```
Cannont invoke 'requires' with an argument list of type 'MyClass'
```

Playground code:

```
import Foundation

public protocol Proto {
    func someFunction()
}

func requires<T: Proto>(param: T) -> Bool
{
    if param is NSObject
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
}


class MyClass:NSObject, Proto {
    var name: String
    required init?(response: String){
        self.name = response
    }

    func someFunction(){
        print(name)
    }
}

var m = MyClass(response: "Hey there")
requires(m) //     Cannont invoke 'requires' with an argument list of type 'MyClass'
```

If I remove the init function it works - do you know why?:

required init?(response: String){
    self.name = response
}

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error with Xcode 7.1.1 in either an iOS or OS X Playground.

Comment: Thanks, I am on 7.2. I will update the question to include Xcode version.

Comment: Update: I was missing the last line "requires(m)". Do you have time to try out again - thanks in advance?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
required init?(response: String) { ... }
```

is a *failable* initializer, therefore

```
var m = MyClass(response: "Hey there")
```

is an *optional* of type `MyClass?`. You have to unwrap the value,
or use optional binding:

```
if let m = MyClass(response: "Hey there") {
    requires(m)
}
```

`MyClass` conforms to `Proto`, but `MyClass?` does not.

Your implementation however does not fail (i.e. return `nil`)
at all, so alternatively you can make the initializer non-failable by removing the question mark:

```
required init(response: String) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by removing `Proto`:

Change:

```
func requires<T: Proto>(param: T) -> Bool
```

to:

```
func requires<T>(param: T) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks JAL, but this will leave out the protocol constrain.